# How to get distinct in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, plsql, sql-server-2012

How to get distinct in a variable

```
Declare @var Nvarchar (500)

SELECT @var = 'EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,
DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT'

SELECT DISTINCT @var
```

Comment: Loop it up into a table variable, then distinct-query that table variable.

Comment: want to take that value in table variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in three steps

1. Split the comma separated values into individual rows
2. Apply distinct on step 1
3. Concatenate the result back to comma separated values

*Query Links to do it*

Step 1: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305493/3349551)

Step 2 : Select `Distinct` from above result

Step 3 : [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution here,
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/15/sql-server-remove-duplicate-entry-from-comma-delimited-string-udf/

Comment: Links get stale. Could you summarize the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for solving this problem using in-memory tables.

```
    DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(500)
    SELECT @var = 'EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,EQUITY,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT,DEBT'

    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (items NVARCHAR(500)) 
    DECLARE @distinctTable TABLE (items NVARCHAR(500)) 
    DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1) = ',' --- Specify the delimiter
    DECLARE @idx INT     
    DECLARE @section NVARCHAR(500)     
    DECLARE @ouput NVARCHAR(500)

    SELECT @idx = 1     
        IF LEN(@var)<1 OR @var IS NULL  RETURN     

    WHILE @idx!= 0     
    BEGIN     
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@var)     
        IF @idx!=0     
            SET @section = LEFT(@var,@idx - 1)     
        ELSE     
            SET @section = @var    

        IF(LEN(@section)>0)
            INSERT INTO @tempTable(Items) VALUES(@section)     

        SET @var = RIGHT(@var,LEN(@var) - @idx)     
        IF LEN(@var) = 0 BREAK     
    END 

    INSERT @distinctTable (items) 
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @tempTable

    SET @ouput = ''
    SELECT @ouput = @ouput + items + @delimiter FROM @distinctTable
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@ouput, 0, LEN(@ouput))
```